# Jquery conflict. Image gallery and countdown timer

Tags: jquery

Working on a personal website. I have two things that use jquery to operate -- an image gallery and a countdown timer. I know that jquery is getting confused/not functioning correctly because of the different libraries and files. I've tried to use jquery's noconflict() but have been unsuccessful. I can only run either the gallery or the countdown timer if I comment out the others code completely.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='camera-css'  href='CSS/camera.css' type='text/css' media='all'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/countdown/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/countdown/icomonn.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/scripts.js"></script>
    <!-- Camera Gallery JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/camera.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/camera.js"></script>                 
    <!-- Circular Countdown JS -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/jquery.ccountdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]> <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/lte-ie7.js"></script> <![endif]-->

    <script>
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#gallery').camera({
                height: '400px',
                pagination: false,
                thumbnails: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>         
    .fluid_container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 90%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="red">
    <a name="C & I"> </a>
    <p> C & I </p>

    <div class="ccounter">
        <input class="knob days" data-width="160" data-min="0" data-max="365" data-displayPrevious=true data-fgColor="#000000" data-readOnly="true" value="1">
        <input class="knob hour" data-width="160" data-min="0" data-max="24" data-displayPrevious=true data-fgColor="#000000" data-readOnly="true" value="1">
        <input class="knob minute" data-width="160" data-min="0" data-max="60" data-displayPrevious=true data-fgColor="#000000" data-readOnly="true" value="1">
        <input class="knob second" data-width="160" data-min="0" data-max="60" data-displayPrevious=true data-fgColor="#000000" data-readOnly="true" value="0" data-bgcolor="#eee">
    </div>

<script>
$(".ccounter").ccountdown(2015,12,25,'18:00');
</script>




    </section>

    <section class="green">
        <a name="Our Story"></a>
        <p> Our Story </p>


    </section>
    <section class="charcoal">
    <a name="Gallery"></a>
    <h1> Gallery </h1>
        <div class="fluid_container">
            <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="gallery">
                <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/one.gif" data-src="images/slides/one.jpg"></div>

                <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/two.gif" data-src="images/slides/two.jpg"></div>

                <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/road.jpg" data-src="images/slides/road.jpg"></div>

                <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/sea.jpg" data-src="images/slides/sea.jpg"></div>

                <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/shelter.jpg" data-src="images/slides/shelter.jpg"></div>

                <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/tree.jpg" data-src="images/slides/tree.jpg"></div>
            </div><!-- #camera_wrap_2 -->
        </div><!-- .fluid_container -->



    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: why do you want multiple versions of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the camera plugin is added to the first instance of jQuery, but when you are trying to use jQuery it is referring to the second version(1.7.0) so it will not have access to the camera plugin so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/scripts.js"></script>
<!-- Camera Gallery JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/camera.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/camera/camera.js"></script>                 
<script>
var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<!-- Circular Countdown JS -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/jquery.ccountdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]> <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/countdown/lte-ie7.js"></script> <![endif]-->

<script>
    //The camera plugin is added to jq so
    jq(function($){
        $('#gallery').camera({
            height: '400px',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

But another solution you can explore is to use the latest version of jQuery with [jQuery migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) for backward compatibility - to support plugins which are not upgraded to newer version of jQuery

Comment: This got me really close! My gallery is stuck on the loaded screen and I'm still having an error, but the gallery itself shows up!!

Comment: Made it live so you can see the problem!  www.ianlueninghoener.com/testcoding

Comment: @user2792749 why do you want 2 vesions of jQuery

Comment: @user2792749 you are using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery 1.7 that really does not make any sense... just use 1 version ie jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: I'm using version 1.3 and 1.7.0. There's no 1.7.1

Comment: @user2792749 no... You are using http://www.ianlueninghoener.com/testcoding/JS/camera/jquery.min.js and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js - look at the version numbers in those files - so there is no jQuery 1.3 in your script

Comment: Yes I see you're correct, it doesn't make a difference if use 1.7 or 1.7.1. My problem is now that the camera's transition effects (easing) are not being recognized as a function. If I comment out "jquery.easing.1.3.js" the picture loads but won't transition. Otherwise it says "easing is not a function" and shows the loading icon. I know it has something to do with the noConflict().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77137/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-user2792749).

Comment: That works very nice! I see what you did there now! Thanks :)